# The view 'name' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting this error message, and any of the advice that I've seen does not appear to be applicable; i.e. all views, controllers and models are in the correct folders.

More detail:
I have a master view, which shows a graphical flowchart-like interface for interacting with the application. The user selects the "Open Study" symbol, and I redirect to another view which allows the user to select a Study to work with.

The OpenStudyController code retrieves the selected study and then redirects back to the master view:

```
public ActionResult SelectStudy( Guid? id )
{
    // code elided for clarity

    return RedirectToAction( "ActivateStudy", "Home" );
}
```

HomeController has a method called ActivateStudy(...), which does get invoked with the appropriate environment:

```
public ActionResult ActivateStudy()
{
    // code elided for clarity

    return View();
}
```

As I said, all views, controllers and models are in the correct folders.

When the "return View()" code in ActivateStudy() is executed, the error message occurs:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The view 'ActivateStudy' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.The following locations were searched:
>       ~/Views/Home/ActivateStudy.aspx
>       ~/Views/Home/ActivateStudy.ascx
>       ~/Views/Shared/ActivateStudy.aspx
>       ~/Views/Shared/ActivateStudy.ascx
>       ~/Views/Home/ActivateStudy.cshtml
>       ~/Views/Home/ActivateStudy.vbhtml
>       ~/Views/Shared/ActivateStudy.cshtml
>       ~/Views/Shared/ActivateStudy.vbhtml

What am I missing? Some additional parameter in RedirectToAction(...)? Some new entry in RouteConfig?

Comment: Are you using areas within your application or are all controllers and views in the top-level Controllers & Views folders? Usually with that error you get a list of all the locations it looked for the view. Can you update your question with that list as sometimes that gives a clue?

Comment: Added the search locations as requested. Sorry for the clumsy formatting. I'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, so I'm not sure about the areas. The controllers in question are all under the project's Controllers folder (as are the Models). The views each have their separate folders, under the project View folder. If I could just have a clue as to where to look or what to try...

Comment: Take a look at your ActivateStudy view and see if there's a line that starts with `Layout =`. If so, what is the value being assigned to `Layout`? If that line doesn't exist check your `_ViewStart.cshtml` for the same line.

Comment: Layout = "~Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; and it is in _ViewStart.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` and it contains something like the following you do not need to specify the same layout in each view.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I believe your problem might be related to a missing slash. In your comment you said that your view contained the following line:

```
Layout = "~Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
```

I think that needs to have a slash after the tilde.

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
```

But, as I said, you should be able to remove that line entirely.

Comment: My mistake, there was a "/" after the "~". I tried removing the line and there's no difference. Maybe I should ask a slightly different question: how do I move from one page back to the home page? Is it via the RedirectToAction(...) or is there another mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it, but, in my HomeController.ActivateStudy() method, I return the Home "index" view:

```
public ActionResult ActivateStudy()
{
    // code elided for clarity

    return View( "Index" );
}
```

And this works.

It's at times like these where you realize you really don't know very much. Back to the books and code editor. Learn by doing.